# Is this singleton instance member thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this code:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton m_instance;
    private Singleton()
    {    

    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return m_instance;
        }
    }

    public void CallMe()
    {
       // is this function thread safe ? 
    }
}
```

Is the CallMe method is thread safe, as every instance member function is thread safe? Or will anything generate an exception here? I saw one sample singleton code using locks, do I really need that?

Comment: This may be of use: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx

Comment: It's not technically threadsafe, but the method does nothing so not sure the point.

Comment: [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx)  "Thread safe" by itself doesn't really mean anything.  What, specifically, do you want to ensure that the code will do correctly?  We'd need to know that (and more about how the method is implemented) to know whether that will work in your case.

Comment: Is the Singleton instance immutable?

Answer (score 3):

You've got multiple issues here...

Firstly the Instance property is not necessarily thread safe.

if two threads simultaneously request the property then they could both feasibly find `m_instance` == null`to be`true` at the same time, return two different instances of Singleton but only one would end up being assigned for future calls.

You would need your implementation to be

```
private static lockObject lock = new Object();

public static Singleton Instance
{
    get
    {
      if (m_instance != null) return m_instance;
      lock (lockObject)
            {
                if(m_instance != null) return m_instance;
                return m_instance = new Singleton();
            }
    } 
}
```

Alternatively simply instanciate m_instance in the static constructor.

Secondly even after the first issue is resolved you can't say CallMe() is thread safe, we have no idea what it is doing.

Comment: I got you, but the CallMe is not resolved here. Why i need lock over there..

Comment: @VibinKesavan No but you would be using `Singleton.Instance.CallMe()` and the `Instance` part would suffer from problem one, you could have two different instances on which to call `CallMe()`.

Comment: @VibinKesavan Do you understand what thread safe means? CallMe may or maynot be thread safe depending on if it uses external state variables that could be shared between threads. You did not show us the code for CallMe, so therefor we can not say if it is threadsafe or not.

Comment: So you could say if there nothing shared accross this function, i am safe

Comment: the method is thread- safe, no race condition , i know

Comment: @VibinKesavan
If the method is truly thread-safe, (i.e. you wrap field writes and matching reads with a synchronisation lock) then you can say `CallMe` is thread safe.  However with your example you cannot say that `Instance.CallMe()` is thread safe because your current implementation of `Instance` is not thread safe

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `Instance` method is not thread-safe. If it's called twice at the same time, it will return two different instances (and therefore break the singleton pattern).

Without seeing its code, it is impossible to know whether `CallMe` is thread-safe or not.

Comment: I agree your first point, but tell me CallMe is thread safe or not, if not why ? how can i prove it

Comment: @VibinKesavan "Thread Safe" doesn't mean anything, by itself.  You need to be much more specific about what you expect it to do and not do.  What do you *mean* when you say "thread safe"?  Also, without the implementation of the method, or at least some knowledge about what types of things it does or doesn't do, we can't comment further.

Answer (score 1):

That code without any synchronization, is not thread safe without any locking mechanism. The only thread-safe code is one that has a synchronization mechanism.

Comment: Can you explain how? it's just a non static instance member right ? and nothing shared accross ..

Comment: @VibinKesavan are you saying `private static Singleton m_instance;` is non-static?

Comment: static does not mean that methods of this class are synchronized.

Comment: It's just a static reference to the object right? the class or the member function is not static. If you call a member function with a static object reference, does it required synchronization ? function variables will be shared accross ?

Comment: Just because the calls to the method aren't synchronized doesn't mean it's not thread safe.  You can't say "it's not thread safe".  It *might* not be thread safe, depending on what the code is and what it's supposed to do, or it might be.  It's entirely possible that the code will work as intended despite having no synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

There are singletone variants with double locking or nested classes. But the easiest solution in .NET 4.0 and above is to use Lazy property:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Lazy<Singleton> m_instance = new Lazy = new Lazy<Singleton>();
    private Singleton()
    {    

    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public void CallMe()
    {
       // now its threadsafe
    }
}
```

The Lazy constructor takes optionally also creating function, or a [LazyThreadSafetyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode.aspx) enum

The `Singleton.Instance` is now thread safe but not `CallMe()` itself. It can be still called from differend threads and e.g. access the fields and properties of other classes. It doesn't matter whethere the method is in in the singleton instance or not. You should use other mechanisms to ensure thread safety here.

Comment: how about CallMeMethod ? "Instance" method is now threadsafe, but not call me i guess

Comment: Easier still is to just write: `private static Singleton m_instance = new Singleton();`.  It's less code, and equally thread safe.

Comment: @Servy: yes. It is good enough, but it's behavior slightly depends if you execute it on .NET 2.0 or above

Comment: @python_kaa Well, you'd need to be in .NET 4.0+ to have access to Lazy, so if that's an option then so is the code I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Daniel's answer:

```
private readonly object _threadLock = new Object();

public void CallMe() {
   // whatever happens here is not thread-safe

   lock(_threadLock) {

      // this is the simplest form of a locking mechanism
      // code within the lock-block will be thread-safe
      // beware of race conditions ...

   }
}
```

Jon Skeet is an authority in .Net and focuses on C#. Here is a link to his analysis of thread-safe singleton instantiation: [C# in Depth: Implementing Singleton ...](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

Comment: How do you know that the entire contents of the method need to be synchronized?  If there is no access to shared state then there would be no need to lock anything within the method.

Comment: @Servy: I don't know :) ...this is just a simple example based on the OP's question and doesn't address any further details. Your question is valid and would be something only the OP can answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would make CallMe Thread Safe:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton()
    {    

    }

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }

    public void CallMe()
    {
       // Thread Safe
    }
}
```

In other words - let the core framework manage the locking, mutex and volatile stuff for you.